# How do I display an alert after an event has happened in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jqbootstrapvalidation

I want to display an alert after the submit button has been pressed and everything was done successfully. I am using the

> jqBootstrapValidation.js

library to validate that the form is not being sent without values. This is the code that I have right now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<br/>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Email address</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="email" required />
            <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Type something</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="some_field" required />
            <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- or use local jquery -->
<script src="/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(function() {
        $("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation();
    });

</script>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Alerts</h2>
    <p>Form Successful</p>
    <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>Success!</strong> You have filled in the form correctly!
    </div>
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

I want this to appear at the top left-hand corner and then redirect me to another page after 2 seconds or so (for now to the same page) after the validation was successful. Is this possible?

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Alerts</h2>
    <p>Form Successful</p>
    <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>Success!</strong> You have filled in the form correctly!
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe, validation function must be returning a value. Can you check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [documentation](https://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/) there is a `submitSuccess` callback that is fired when the form is successfully validated and submitted.

You can reposition your alert `container` to the top left hand by adding some styling and hide it by default or better use bootstrap modals :) Try this

```
    <div class="container alert-wrapper">
       .... // add alert dialog here
   </div>

 .alert-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:999;
    background: #fff;
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

  $(function () {
      $("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation({
          preventSubmit: true,
          submitError: function ($form, event, errors) {
              // Here handle errors
          },
          submitSuccess: function ($form, event) {

              // Show your Success Message
              $(".alert-wrapper").fadeIn();

              // redirect after two seconds to other page
              window.setTimeout(function () {
                  window.location.href = "https://www.example.com";
              }, 2000);

              event.preventDefault();
          }
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a submitSuccess: function ($form, event)  will triggered when the form is validated successfully..you can used the alert  inside this function ..
In the below code i have used div to display alert message..

```
$("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation(
   {

       preventSubmit: true,
       submitError: function ($form, event, errors) {
           // something to have when submit produces an error ?
           // Not decided if I need it yet
       },
       submitSuccess: function ($form, event) {
           debugger;
           event.preventDefault();

 $('#divid').append('<h2>Alerts</h2> <p>Form Successful</p>    <div class="alert alert-success fadein">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    <strong>Success!</strong> You have filled in the form correctly!
</div> ');


});
```